# ServiceStack.OrmLite fetch using GetByIds() slow when calling many ids?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Somewhere in my code I call this method:

```
public List<T> GetByIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
        var db = OpenDb();
        var value = db.GetByIds<T>(ids);
        CloseDb(db);
        return value;
    }
```

My db grew allot over the last couple of weeks and the number of ids in the IEnumerable is close to 1000 for any given call. When calling this method it just hangs until the thread is aborted.

I can imagine that this method is not suited for handling 1000 ids, perhaps due to the way the query gets build but that just a guess.

Do you perhaps have any experience with this or perhaps know of a good workaround using ServiceStack.Ormlite (3.9.*)?

Thanks!

ps I know I should be using a using block... :-).

Comment: Are you going to show these 1000 rows to the user? In that case, consider paging your resultset. 1000 rows is way too many to show at once. Otherwise...are there any other common denominator for these 1000 rows that you may use? Maybe you could rewrite your query as a join or something similiar instead?

Comment: I think you're right. I'm going to have to retool a part of my repositories to make this work more efficient. Guess premature optimization grows up pretty fast ;-)